# random sampling of many groups within dataframe IF group size is greater than a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, conditional-statements

I'm a newbie.
Consider the following.  For any LOC_ID that has more than 3 unique SUB_IDs, I take a random sample of 3 unique SUB_IDs to piece together a new dataframe with concatenate:

[dataframe_in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6T2C.png)

```
df_concat = pd.DataFrame(columns=['LOC_ID', 'SUB_ID'])

for loc in test_df['LOC_ID'].unique():
    sub_ids = test_df[test_df['LOC_ID'] == loc]['SUB_ID'].unique()
    if len(sub_ids) > 3:
        np.random.seed(622)
        sub_ids_max = np.random.choice(sub_ids, size=3, replace=False)
        df_sample = test_df[test_df['SUB_ID'].isin(sub_ids_max)]
    else:
        df_sample = test_df[test_df['SUB_ID'].isin(sub_ids)]
    df_concat = pd.concat([df_concat, df_sample], ignore_index=True)
```

[dataframe_out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVDkn.png)

The following is the real case where I also have a year component with 6 years.  Each LOC_ID within locids_sub has more than 10 unique SUB_IDs in at least one year.  Per LOC_ID, per year, I need to ensure that there are no more than 10 unique SUB_ID's:

```
max_subid = 10
years = df_bb['Year'].unique()

count_df = df_bb.groupby(['LOC_ID', 'Year']).nunique().reset_index()
locids_sub = count_df[count_df['SUB_ID'] > max_subid]['LOC_ID'].unique()

# Subset df_bb by locids_sub
df_bb_sub = df_bb[df_bb['LOC_ID'].isin(locids_sub)][['Year', 'LOC_ID', 'SUB_ID']]

df_concat = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_bb.columns)  # Initializing df

for year in years:
    for loc in locids_sub:
        sub_ids = df_bb_sub[(df_bb_sub['Year'] == year) & (df_bb_sub['LOC_ID'] == loc)]['SUB_ID'].unique()
        if len(sub_ids) > max_subid:
            np.random.seed(year+int(loc[-2:]))
            sub_ids_max = np.random.choice(sub_ids, size=max_subid, replace=False)
            df_sample = df_bb[df_bb['SUB_ID'].isin(sub_ids_max)]
        else:
            df_sample = df_bb[df_bb['SUB_ID'].isin(sub_ids)]
        df_concat = pd.concat([df_concat, df_sample], ignore_index=True)
```

With 6 years, 1460 LOC_IDs in locids_sub, and 1828201 rows in df_bb, this takes 30 minutes to run.
Please let me know how to make this more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
out = (
    df.drop_duplicates(['LOC_ID', 'SUB_ID'])
      .assign(count=lambda x: x.groupby('LOC_ID').transform('nunique'))
      .loc[lambda x: x.pop('count') >= 3].groupby('LOC_ID').sample(n=3)
)
print(out)

# Output
  LOC_ID  SUB_ID
5      a     903
0      a     222
3      a     888
8      b     314
7      b     721
6      b     231
```

If you have a `Year` column maybe you can it to the previous code:

```
out = (
    df.drop_duplicates(['Year', 'LOC_ID', 'SUB_ID'])
      .assign(count=lambda x: x.groupby(['Year', 'LOC_ID']).transform('nunique'))
      .loc[lambda x: x.pop('count') >= 3].groupby(['Year', 'LOC_ID']).sample(n=3)
)
```

Comment: Seems like a nice approach!

Comment: @mozway. Thanks. I try to find a way to use only one `groupby` but the size is different for the second use :(

Comment: TBH I only skimmed though OP's post. Too hard to read on a small screen ;) do you have the input as DataFrame?

Comment: `{'LOC_ID': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
 'SUB_ID': [222, 222, 222, 888, 918, 903, 231, 721, 314]}`

Comment: Thanks! You can do it in a single groupby step with apply

Comment: I know for `apply` but I don't know which is the worst :P

Comment: I don't think `apply` on groups is necessarily bad. After all everything is still vectorized within the groups.

Comment: You are right. It depends on how many groups there are in the dataframe.

Comment: After running a few tests, `apply` is faster on a small number of groups but quite slower on many groups (tested on 100 groups)

Comment: Thanks @Corralien! Now I'm trying to frame your code inside a loop for the year component (perhaps it can be done with a direct edit of your code).  ```years = df['Year'].unique() ; df_concat = pd.DataFrame(columns = df_.columns) ; for year in years: out = (df[df['Year'] == year].drop_duplicates(['LOC_ID', 'SUB_ID']).assign...) ; df_concat = pd.concat([df_concat, out], ignore_index=True)```    However, on the assign part, it throws the error:  "Wrong number of items passed 21, placement implies 1"   Any thoughts there?

Comment: @Corralien found a faster way ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can shuffle the whole unduplicated dataframe and select 3 rows (quite fast):

```
(df.drop_duplicates(['LOC_ID', 'SUB_ID'])
   .sample(frac=1).groupby('LOC_ID').head(n=3)
```

Or `groupby+apply` (slow):

```
(df
 .groupby('LOC_ID', group_keys=False)
 .apply(lambda g: g if len(g2:=g.drop_duplicates('SUB_ID'))<3
                  else g2.sample(n=3))
 )
```

Output:

```
  LOC_ID  SUB_ID
5      a     903
4      a     918
3      a     888
8      b     314
7      b     721
6      b     231
```

*NB. If you like this, still consider accepting @Corralien's answer. I would probably not have made an attempt without his answer*

Comment: @jmintz4. Assuming you are using Python 3.8 or above to use the walrus operator (`:=`).

Comment: If the group has less than 3 records, I think it should be dropped. With `head(3)` you can have 1 or 2 rows only for a group, no?

Comment: I got it to work by reducing the original df down to only the LOC_ID and SUB_ID columns, running it through your code, extracting the resulting SUB_IDs (those that were randomly selected), and then looking those SUB_IDs up in the original df.  The resulting df has only records where the number of unique SUB_IDs (per LOC_ID, per Year) has been reduced to 10.  Then I combine that with the df where SUB_IDs were not touched (unique < 10).  Thanks.